# probleme to upload multiple file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm getting an error when I try to upload multiple files in a form.
this is my model:

```py
class Delivery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("Client"), related_name=_("delivery_user")
    )
    pickup_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=_("pickup_address"))
    destination_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=_("destination_address"))
    operation_date = models.DateField(
        _("desired pickup date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False
    )
    operation_time = models.TimeField(
        _("desired pickup date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False
    )
    document = models.FileField(
        help_text=_("Delivery Documets"),
        verbose_name=_("Delivery Certificates"),
        upload_to="documents/deliveries_documents/",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created_at",)
        verbose_name = _("Delivery")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Deliveries")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("delivery:unconf-delivery-details", args=[self.id])
```

I used an exemple from Django website to handle the multiple upload of files and this is the form and the view for this model:
**View.py**

```py
class DeliveryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView, FormView):
    model = Delivery
    form_class = UserDeliveryForm
    template_name = "deliveries/customer/edit_deliveries.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("delivery:operation-form", kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_active

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist("decument")
        if form.is_valid():
            for file in files:
                self.Delivery.objects.create(document=file)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**Form.py**

```py
class UserDeliveryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = [
            "user",
            "pickup_address",
            "destination_address",
            "operation_date",
            "operation_time",
            "document",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "operation_date": forms.DateInput(
                format=("%d %B %Y"),
                attrs={"class": "form-control mb-2 delivery-form", "placeholder": "JJ-MM-AAAA"},
            ),
            "operation_time": forms.TimeInput(
                attrs={"type": "time", "class": "form-control mb-2 delivery-form"},
            ),
            "document": forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple": True}),
            "user": forms.Select(),
            "pickup_address": forms.Select(),
            "destination_address": forms.Select(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["user"].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control mb-2 delivery-form", "Placeholder": "Client "})
        self.fields["pickup_address"].widget.attrs.update(
            {"class": "form-control mb-2 dropdown delivery-form", "Placeholder": "Addresse de ramassage "}
        )
        self.fields["destination_address"].widget.attrs.update(
            {"class": "form-control mb-2 delivery-form", "Placeholder": "Addresse de destination"}
        )
        self.fields["document"].widget.attrs.update(
            {"class": "form-control mb-2 delivery-form", "Placeholder": "document"}
        )
```

when I test the form I get this error:
*AttributeError at /delivery/new_delivery
'DeliveryCreateView' object has no attribute 'object'*
I don't now what is the problem exactly, the file I tried to upload are some picture *.jpg.

Comment: Your data model doesn't make sense. If one Delivery is to have multiple documents, you'll need a separate model like `DeliveryDocument` that has the file field.

Comment: Also, `operation_date` and `operation_time` should probably be combined to a single datetime.

Comment: Thirdly, `related_name`s must not be localizable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, for the related name the address model return the address name so I'm using it to be dispayed. I think it's not a big problem using separated field for time and date. for the multiple files the documentations says that it's possible to have a single field in the model and store multiple files.

Comment: Can you link that part of documentation?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files). I think I need a separate model as you said.

Comment: Yep. That documentation doesn't say you can store multiple files per field. (You can't, since the concrete SQL field only stores a storage-relative path to the file.)